# Positions in Dota 2 - What do they mean?

Tags: dota-2

Coming from LoL, I'm trying to watch some DOTA. I'm first doing some research on the teams I see, and the positions, contrary to LoL, are not really labeled. They are 1-2-3-4-5.

http://wiki.teamliquid.net/dota2/Evil_Geniuses

Can these positions be put into context? Like 1 is pretty much the top laner, or is it interchangeable?

If you cannot link them to LoL positions (top, jng, mid, adc, top) could you at least explain what is different between the roles? What do you expect from someone that has the role 1 instead of 2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are called [farming positions](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/dota2/Farm_Dependency). In a nutshell, they rank how much farm (gold and XP) each player needs. Position 1 needs the most, so they usually play in the safelane (that's bottom for Radiant and top for Dire). Position 2 and 3 usually correspond to midlane carries and offlaners respectively, while 4 and 5 are supports.

Comment: Worth noting that the reason they're commonly referred to by farming position instead of "mid", "safelaner", etc. is because the laning is very flexible. For example, some games involve the carry with #1 farming priority going offlane!

Comment: Also important to keep in mind that competitive 1 pos and 2 pos players will often swap roles depending on their draft.

Answer (score 2):

Building on quartata's answer:

- Position 1 is safelane carry and could be seen as a LoL ADC
- Position 2 is usually mid and is the LoL mid
- Position 3 is the offlaner and is the LoL top laner, usually more tanky to handle the safelaner and support harass
- Position 4 and 5 are supports (for the safelaner) or roamer

You will sometimes have a jungler that will take position 4 and usually will try to roam and gank, but it is not a set position like in LoL.

Also, contrary to LoL, you don't have the two "tops" facing each other, you have the safelane carry facing the opposing offlaner.

You can have more information there:

- http://wiki.teamliquid.net/dota2/Farm_Dependency
- https://purgegamers.true.io/purge/hero-roles/

Comment: 3. position can be solo on safelane, and supports with 1. position on offlane, it is very common when you have agressive supports. So I think 3. position can be define as SOLO not offlane,